# where are all themes,uiid and images hidden in new version of cn1

Tags: codenameone

I've updated my cn1 version. Before there are all the pre-installed themes ,uiid, images shown in Gui builder. But now there are nothing there. I want to use the existing uiid for instance 'titleArea' properties in a container but change the properties of toolbar and titleArea. I am curious where are they hidden?

In barebone theme,there's nothing but it takes default setting for button, toolbar, titleArea etc.

[image]

In StateMachine theme, all the default setting(uiids and images etc) are visible and I can reuse them where necessary.

[image]

How is it possible the default uiids,images and theme are still there in barebone though its literally empty in Gui Builder.

Comment: A screenshot would go a long way in explaining this. I have no idea what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your theme is missing. Check the size of the res file, verify that you aren't using the XML-Team Mode which might be overriding your content.

Comment: if I choose theme flat blue or other, they exist but I can't find them if I choose native theme. XML team mode has nothing to do with them. When the native theme is choosed while creating the project, there is only src folder (no theme folder) in the project.

Comment: src has a res file below it. The theme is in the res directory which in netbeans you can only see in the file view not in the project view

Comment: I didn't find them. Look at the project here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ATnICIY2S8LUdta0F5NXYzamM/view

Comment: We don't run projects for individual users as that can't possibly scale. Re-reading your edited problem description it seems you have 2 themes in the project and the code is picking the wrong one for an old GUI builder project. You need to override the initTheme method in the state machine and load the right theme